# text field in AS3 to have auto complete, suggestion

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to make a text field in AS3 to have auto complete, suggestion that words should load from an external .txt file. basically the function of that text-input box was to get an input from user and navigate to the page. for example if user types control tower and hits enter it will navigate to the page, but right now its like a lot of if /else if functions assigned. my idea is to add a smart search bar. so auto complete or suggestion of words can help in easy navigation as i define. please help me out.

Present code for the text field that takes search input.

```
userSearch.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pressEnter);
function pressEnter(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
if(event.keyCode == 13){
      trace("Enter Pressed");

    if(userSearch.text == "Terminal"){
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 5");

}
    else if(userSearch.text == "terminal"){
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 5");
}
    else if(userSearch.text == "Control Tower"){
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 6");
}
    else if(userSearch.text == "Control tower"){
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 6");
}
    else(userSearch.text = "please review typed word");         

}
```

}

Like you see above i have to manually assign each possible words. also i would like to take all typed words in either small letter or caps that can reduce my work in writing possible search terms by users and their by to assign each keyword to navigate to each scene.
Please guide me.

Comment: First, instead of a .txt, make a .xml. the data is simple, keyword and the destination the keyword leads to. Second, on startup of your application, parse that xml and put it in a dictionary, keywords are key, the destinations are values. Then, the moment somebody types something in the textfield (some kind of event) check through the entire dictionary with string.substring. This will be slow, but if your list of keywords is short, it will work just fine. good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the idea sir but im totally new to scripting field, this app i made for my team in order to refresh their knowledge on particular fields, so i made it out of few simple codes, i don't know anything  deeper in this. I have updated my question with the code assigned for that search text input. it may look weird but correct me in that and to link that xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [this tutorial](http://www.xtydigitaldesign.ca/autoComplete.php) with step by step, details and source code.
Just replace the hard coded array with your .txt content data